# What is the difference between ROS Noetic Ninjemys and ROS Melodic Morenia?

Tags: ros, robotics

Which of the two distributions do you recommend to start learning ROS? And what is the purpose of each one?

Comment: I think ROS distributions are tied to the operating system; Melodic is for 18.04, Noetic is for 20.04.

Comment: @Chuck yup, they're tied to different os distros. They also have subtle differences between ros versions.

Answer (score 1):

For ROS1 distros there really isn't a whole lot of difference *on the surface*. The biggest of them is what OS they're written for. For example Noetic is written for Ubuntu 20.04 while Melodic is for Ubuntu 18.04(among other operations systems). Choose whatever one fits the OS you're running; but I'd recommend Noetic since it's the most recent for ROS1. Also, Noetic targets Python3 where all other ROS1 distros target Python2.7.